# How to use functions exported using scalajs in reactjs components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scala.js

I have tried exporting some functions to the `main.js` file in scalajs using `@JSExportTopLevel` annotation, as explained in the [Export Scala.js APIs to JavaScript](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/interoperability/export-to-javascript.html) scalajs documentation and building the `main.js` as explained [here](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/building.html).

This results in `main.js` from which I am able to make use the functions exported in the scalajs code.

Now I want to use these exported functions in my reactjs components. For this I tried following steps:

1. Copy the `main.js` file in the `public` folder
2. Include the javascript file in the `index.html`, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
```

Now, if I load the app in the browser and try to use these functions in the browser console, it works fine:

```
console.log(foo());
```

But I am not the utilise these functions in reactjs components:

```js
import React from 'react';

const RuleEditor = () => {

    console.log(foo());

    return (
        <>
        </>
    );
};

export default RuleEditor;
```

I always get the following compilation error:

```
foo is not defined  no-undef
```

I do understand that reactjs is not able to recognise the function as I haven't really specified where to get that function from but I am not really sure how to achieve it. I have gone to couple of other stackoverflow posts where some suggestions where to look for it in `window` object but I didn't find those functions there.

Please suggest a proper way to make use of functions exported from scalajs in reactjs components. TIA.

Comment: How is he React.js component trying to call the function? You showed us the code that works, but not the one that doesn't. That makes it hard for us to help you.

Comment: @sjrd `console.log(foo())` when tried in the browser returns correct result but the same statement in a reactjs component fails to compile

Comment: @sjrd update the question with example code. Hope it is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exporting objects/classes/functions as top level exports put them in Javascript global scope.

```scala
class Foo(val x: Int) {
  @JSExport
  def square(): Int = x*x // note the (), omitting them has a different behavior
  @JSExport("foobar")
  def add(y: Int): Int = x+y
}
```

You can utilise these functions in the scripts embedded in html or in scalajs as shown [here](https://github.com/iamsmkr/parser-playground/blob/main/js/src/main/scala/com/iamsmkr/simplearithmeticparser/Validator.scala#L9).

But if you need to use these functions in a nodejs app, you need to export these functions from a module. We need to add the following in the `build.sbt`. Read more [here](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/project/module.html).

```scala
scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withModuleKind(ModuleKind.ESModule) }
```

Now, we can make use of the exported functions in a nodejs app by importing them like so:

```js
import { square, add } from './main'
```

If you wish to export these functions from a module named other than `main`, provide module id for each exported function like so:

```scala
class Foo(val x: Int) {
  @JSExport("square", "my-math")
  def square(): Int = x*x // note the (), omitting them has a different behavior
  @JSExport("foobar", "my-math")
  def add(y: Int): Int = x+y
}
```

and use it like so:

```js
import { square, add } from './my-math'
```